# Simulating Menu Press action not working on all the Android

Tags: android, instrumentation, keyevent, android-optionsmenu

As in the later Androids, the menu button has been removed, I call the following code to open menu items when some one taps once in the UI.

```
    public void singleTapOnImage(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Single tap View menu option");  
    new Thread(new Runnable() {         
        public void run() {
            Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();  
            inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
        }   
    }).start();
}
```

This, code opens the Options Menu on some Android devices but not on all.
Can you please help me with a solution that works on all Android Devices and also if there is a better way to open the Options Menu, then it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was simple. Just call `openOptionsMenu()` in the activity.